# MVC -String or binary data would be truncated.\r\nThe statement has been terminated

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I understand that this error means that I am trying to insert a value that is larger than what I allow in my database but I cannot see which value is causing the problem

**This is where I am inserting the data:**

```
UserActivity log = new UserActivity();

ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

log.UserEmail = User.Identity.Name;
log.SQL_Query = queryString;
log.Query_Start = String.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss}", start);
log.Query_End = String.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss}", end);
log.Query_Time = String.Format("{0:mm:ss.ff}", Duration.ToString());                   

db.UserActivities.Add(log);

db.SaveChanges();
```

**This is the database table definition:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserActivities] (
    [Id]            INT            NOT NULL,
    [UserEmail]     VARCHAR (255)  NOT NULL,
    [SQL_Query ]    VARCHAR (1000) NOT NULL,
    [Query_Start]   VARCHAR (11)   NULL,
    [Query_End]     VARCHAR (11)   NULL,
    [Query_Time]    VARCHAR (11)   NULL,
    [Error_Message] VARCHAR (255)  NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

**In the debugger I using the length command to look at the length of the values I am passing in, this was my results:**

```
        log.UserEmail.Length;
        21
        log.Query_End.Length;
        8
        log.Query_Start.Length;
        8
        log.SQL_Query.Length;
        32
```

**This is a sample of the data that would be entered**
[image]

**This is the UserActivity class**

```
public class UserActivity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    public string SQL_Query { get; set; }
    public string Query_Start { get; set; }
    public string Query_End { get; set; }
    public string Query_Time { get; set; }
    public string Error_Message { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: why are u using varchars for time? Why not just use datetime and store that? obviously one of the items is too long, debug it

Comment: Can you show the `UserActivity` class definition, the `Duration` variable definition/assignment, and give an example of a value in the `Query_Time` field/property? I'm suspecting the issue may be with `Query_Time`.

Comment: If I have `DateTime start = DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);`, and `DateTime end  = DateTime.Now;`, and `TimeSpan Duration = end - start;` then set `log.Query_Time = String.Format("{0:mm:ss.ff}", Duration.ToString()` then `log.QueryTime` is equal to `"00:02:00.0030060"`.

Comment: Query_Time is equal to "00:00:00" which is the same amount of characters as the start and end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the logic shown below, I'm getting a value of `"00:02:00.0030060"` in `log.Query_Time`, which is why I suspect that is where you are having an issue. That string is 16 characters, where your `Query_Time` column in the database is only 11 characters.

```
public class UserActivity
{
  public string UserEmail { get; set; }
  public string SQL_Query { get; set; }
  public string Query_Start { get; set; }
  public string Query_End { get; set; }
  public string Query_Time { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  UserActivity log = new UserActivity();
  DateTime start = DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
  DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
  TimeSpan Duration = end - start;

  log.UserEmail = "email@here.gov";
  log.SQL_Query = "exec FTSP_FTProblemsByCategory 5";
  log.Query_Start = String.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss}", start);
  log.Query_End = String.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss}", end);
  log.Query_Time = String.Format("{0:mm:ss.ff}", Duration.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem here is the formatting of the duration, I'm assuming that this is a TimeSpan object.  Using what you've got at the moment if your duration was 3 minutes, 45 seconds and 210 miliseconds your Query_Time variable is set to: 00:03:45.210000.

You will want to use the following instead of your current String.Format:

```
log.Query_Time = Duration.ToString("mm\\:ss\\.ff");
```

That will give you an output like 03:45.21 which I imagine is what you were aiming for.